# Capture screen video in android without root with javacv

Tags: android, video, javacv

I am making an application in which i need to make the video of the screen of user interaction with app.

I searched a lot and found that some are able to make videos by using javacv and set of images but they are not able to record sound.

can I want example code of how to create a video from a set of images

**EDITED :**

i want to make a video from a set of images.
is that possible ?

Comment: Finally I got success in doing what I needed........

Comment: i think you should add your answer here so other people can be helped from that.